# How do I prevent a url from being displayed outside Messenger webview? e.g. directly in a browser

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm working on an experience that should happen exclusively inside Messenger. How do I prevent an url from being displayed outside the webview. For example: user taps on 'Copy Link' and opens it in a browser.

Also, any way to disable the share button in a Messenger webview altogether?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent the user from opening the link in another browser. Best you could do is detect the user agent on the page, then display an error that redirects to the bot and then resend a message with the URL button.

You can also set webview_share_button to false on the url button:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/url